# Getting Error - #<Google::Apis::ServerError: unsupported proxy proxy.xyz.com:8080> while configuring proxy for google-api-ruby-client-0.10.0 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, google-api-ruby-client

I am using **google-drive-ruby** gem for integrating Google-Drive in my rails project. **google-drive-ruby** gem has run time dependency on **google-api-ruby-client** gem.

I am trying to configure proxy in ***configure_client*** method of ***http_client_adapter.rb***

```
def configure_client(client, request) 
    client.transparent_gzip_decompression = true
    if true #request.options.proxy
        #proxy = request.options.proxy
        proxy = URI('http://proxy.xyz.com:8080')
        proxy_user = '*******'
        proxy_pass = '*******'
        client.proxy = sprintf('%s:%d', proxy.host, proxy.port)
        if proxy_user && proxy_pass 
            client.set_proxy_auth proxy_user, proxy_pass
        end
    end
end
```

Error trace is below :

Google::Apis::ServerError: unsupported proxy #
        from D:/g_drive_local/BMajor/gems/google-api-ruby-client-0100/google-api-ruby-client-0.10.0/lib/google/apis/core/upload.rb:231:in `rescue in send_start_command'
        from D:/g_drive_local/BMajor/gems/google-api-ruby-client-0100/google-api-ruby-client-0.10.0/lib/google/apis/core/upload.rb:214:in`send_start_command'
        from D:/g_drive_local/BMajor/gems/google-api-ruby-client-0100/google-api-ruby-client-0.10.0/lib/google/apis/core/upload.rb:279:in `execute_once'
        from D:/g_drive_local/BMajor/gems/google-api-ruby-client-0100/google-api-ruby-client-0.10.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:107:in`block (2 levels) in execute'
        from D:/Ruby/ruby gems/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:61:in `block in retriable'
        from D:/Ruby/ruby gems/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in`times'
        from D:/Ruby/ruby gems/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `retriable'
        from D:/g_drive_local/BMajor/gems/google-api-ruby-client-0100/google-api-ruby-client-0.10.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:104:in`block in execute'
        from D:/Ruby/ruby gems/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:61:in `block in retriable'
        from D:/Ruby/ruby gems/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in`times'
        from D:/Ruby/ruby gems/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `retriable'
        from D:/g_drive_local/BMajor/gems/google-api-ruby-client-0100/google-api-ruby-client-0.10.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:96:in`execute'
        from D:/g_drive_local/BMajor/gems/google-api-ruby-client-0100/google-api-ruby-client-0.10.0/lib/google/apis/core/base_service.rb:353:in `execute_or_queue_command'
        from D:/g_drive_local/BMajor/gems/google-api-ruby-client-0100/google-api-ruby-client-0.10.0/generated/google/apis/drive_v3/service.rb:579:in`create_file'
        from D:/g_drive_local/BMajor/gems/google-drive-ruby-200/google-drive-ruby-2.0.0/lib/google_drive/session.rb:409:in `upload_from_source'
        from D:/g_drive_local/BMajor/gems/google-drive-ruby-200/google-drive-ruby-2.0.0/lib/google_drive/session.rb:308:in`upload_from_file'
        from (irb):2
        from D:/Ruby/ruby gems/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from D:/Ruby/ruby gems/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in`start'
        from D:/Ruby/ruby gems/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in`require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing some hit and trial I resolved this issue myself. 
This is how I configured proxy in **http_client_adapter.rb** :

```
def configure_client(client, request) 
    client.transparent_gzip_decompression = true
    if true #request.options.proxy
        #proxy = request.options.proxy
        proxy = URI('http://proxy.xyz.com:8080')
        proxy_user = '*******'
        proxy_pass = '*******'
        client.proxy = 'http://username:password@hostname:port'
        if proxy_user && proxy_pass 
            client.set_proxy_auth proxy_user, proxy_pass
        end
    end
end
```